# Series diode instead of a flyback one

Tags: mosfet, diodes, flyback

My question is can I use a diode in series with a MOSFET, instead of pusing it as a flyback diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmZ6DG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No, the diode in the second diagram does not protect against voltage spikes. It only causes a voltage drop and is further totally superfluous.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXGtE3X2k7Y

Comment: Why did you think your solution would work. Curious.  But I give a +1 vote because it is a good beginner's question.

Comment: No, but a diode can be reversed biased across the mosfet, but it already has one built in, so you don't need an external flyback diode if you are using an IFR530 in your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  If the inductor were perfect, and the switching of the FET instantaneous, then the inductor would generate an **infinite** voltage when you turned off the switch.  Even in our imperfect world, putting the diode in series with the FET source will just burn out both devices while protecting neither.

Inductors do not want to change current instantaneously.  You *must* give that current someplace to go when you turn off the FET.  There are various ways to arrange catch diodes, but you have to answer the question "where will the current go if it **WILL** go someplace?"

Comment: @user6740407 Think of the current in an inductor as a freight train. If you suddenly try and stop it by placing a brick wall in front of it so it stops very quickly it will make a big mess. Instead, give it a nice path for it to slow down gracefully. In this case, that would be a path around the inductor that allows current to flow.